# UIImage not appearing in prototype cells in UITableView (Swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios8, uiimageview, autolayout

I have created a UITableView Containing 10 cells, each of which have a UIImageView attached to them using auto-layout[image]

The table is populated in my BackTableViewController by the code:

```
TableArray = ["Home Page", "Membership Card", "Recent News", "Fitness  Schedule", "Training Log", "Pool Lap Calculator", "Martial Arts Schedule", "Pool Schedule", "Comments", "Acknowledgements"]
```

The issue is that none of these images appear in the table until the cell is selected while run. I am out of ideas as to why this is... anyone?

Thanks

Edit: BackTableViewController

import UIKit

class BackTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var TableArray = [String]()

var ImageArray = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    TableArray = ["Home Page", "Membership Card", "Recent News", "Fitness Schedule", "Training Log", "Pool Lap Calculator", "Martial Arts Schedule", "Pool Schedule", "Comments", "Acknowledgements"]

    ImageArray = ["home-50.png","credit_card-50.png","info-50.png","math-50.png","news-50.png","report_card-50.png","weightlift-50.png"]

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TableArray.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableArray[indexPath.row], forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = TableArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}
}
```

Comment: Prototype cells don't quite work the way I think you're expecting them to. are you experience with tableview? So I can try and provide a detailed enough answer. 

Have you hooked up all the tableview datasource and delegates to the class, also you need to give the cell an identifier in the attributes section.

Comment: The datasource and delegate are hooked up for the entire tableview. Additionally, the cell identifiers are provided for each cell corresponding to the array I have set up in my BackTableViewController.

Comment: ...these images appear in the table until the cell is selected. What this mean exactly?

Comment: Please share your code of your `BackTableViewController`

Comment: BackTableViewController added, and when I say the images do not appear until the cell is selected, I mean that until the user taps a cell or holds it, the image is not visible, but as soon as they do it appears as long as they hold it.

Comment: Try to invoke the visual debugger to see where the images are before selecting the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need **one** prototype cell with a reuse identifier. The clue is in the name "prototype". Think of them as blueprints all cells are based off.

In your view controller class (which should be a `UITableViewDelegate` if it is a `UITableViewContoller`) you specify the number of rows with this method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourArray.count
}
```

This is the method that takes care of displaying the right info in the right row of the table.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //We create a cell from our prototype that we gave an identifier to in our storyborad.
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ItemCell") as! UITableViewCell

    //Create a single instance of an item from our items array. we use the indexpath.row that was passed into this method as the index for the array.
    let item = yourArray[indexPath.row]

    //You can go into your array and get the right info out regarding this row by using the indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = item
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: item)

    //Finally this method returns the correctly configured cell fro the tableview to display.
    return cell
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go... and I set it up properly using your method, however I am now getting 'fatal error: Array index out of range' when I run my app.

Comment: Nevermind dude, I messed up the code, and then forgot to account for the fact that I didn't have enough images to suit my cells, and therefore there was an out of range error. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving "Center x" constraint instead of leading space for the image view, and you should give it width and height constraint also.

Comment: This does not do anything unfortunately... The images are still not seen until the cell is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your cell identifier using Interface Builder in the Attributes Inspector:

[image]

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to pass the cell identifier as you set before, something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   // set the identifier cell, not TableArray[indexPath.row]
   var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
   cell.textLabel?.text = TableArray[indexPath.row]
   return cell
}
```

I hope this help you.